# is package.config file really necessary for loading the dll in projects?

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

is package.config file still really necessary for loading the dll in projects, although the dll references are also there in project file ?

Also is it necessary the nuget dll reference should also needs to be updated in web.config file ? is the project will not work if the web.config nuget dll reference is not done

please clarify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

packages.config isn't required for compilation in and of itself but is used to restore the missing packages/version combinations to the path that the .csproj file is expecting them.

As for the web.config references, I'm assuming you mean the assembly redirects. This is useful when multiple versions of the same package are defined throughout the dependencies; the redirect will inform the application to use a single version of the library.